# How can I append something to a result of a function and store that in a Variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a Program that will work out the max. profit and one function is "Steigung" which I need to work out the optimum price.

So what I have is:

```
def Steigung ():
    Propreis=eval(raw_input("Dein hoechster Preis:"))
    Satmenge=eval(raw_input("Wie viele leute werden es kaufen:"))
    if Propreis >0 and Satmenge >0:
        print(-1*Satmenge/Propreis)
```

and this works fine but what I want to do is to add the Value I specified  in "Satmenge" so that the result is for example if Satmenge = 100000 and Propreis = 6 is -16666x+100000  instead of -16666 by itself and how can I store the desired result in a variable to use later?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use eval, if you want an int then cast to an int. If you want to use the value outside the function then you should return it

Comment: The comment above works well if you're using Python 3.  Since your code references `raw_input(...)` however, I don't think you are.  You can read a float or int from the user in Python 2 with just regular `input(...)`, for example: `Propreis = input("Dein hoechster Preis:")`.  Also it would be useful to run pep8 on your code file to use standard Python naming conventions, etc.

Comment: @tedmiston:  The Python 2-style `input` is subject to most (all?) of the same security flaws as `eval` --- the user can make your program do almost anything he or she wants.  That's why it was dropped from Python 3 and replaced with Python 2's `raw_input`, which Python 3 renamed to just `input`.  A `try` block containing `Propreis = int(raw_input('...'))` is _much_ safer.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Of course, you're right.  I'll add the doc link to `input()` so OP has the complete picture. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score 2):

You can return multiple values in the following way:

```
def Steigung ():
    Propreis=eval(raw_input("Dein hoechster Preis:"))
    Satmenge=eval(raw_input("Wie viele leute werden es kaufen:"))
    if Propreis >0 and Satmenge >0:
        print(-1*Satmenge/Propreis)
    return Propreis, Satmenge
```

And store the returned values like that:

```
a, b = Steigung()
```